# Get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Orders#show in Ruby on Rails app after resetting db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I receive the following error in my Ruby on Rails application when trying to 
render forms.

In particular, I get this error:

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: deliveries.order_id: SELECT 
"deliveries".* FROM "deliveries" WHERE "deliveries"."order_id" = ?
```

Citing these two lines as the cause in the show.html.haml file:

```
= render @order.deliveries

= render "deliveries/form"
```

This is form.html.haml file:

```
=simple_form_for([@order, @order.deliveries.build]) do |f|
   =f.input :name, input_html: { class: "form-control"}
   =f.input :deliveryaddress, input_html: { class: "form-control"}
   =f.input :deliverytime, input_html: { class: "form-control"}
   =f.input :notes, input_html: { class: "form-control"}
   %br/
   =f.button :submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
```

Here is my partial for deliveries _deliveries.html.haml:

```
%p= delivery.name
%p= delivery.deliveryaddress
%p= delivery.deliverytime
%p= delivery.notes
```

This is my deliveries_controller.rb:

```
class DeliveriesController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])  #find the order the delivery is   associated with in the controller
      @deilvery = @order.deliveries.create(params[:order].permit(:name, :deliveryaddress, :deliverytime, :notes))
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    end
end
```

Also, I have already tried 'rake db:drop db:create db:migrate' and 'rake db:test:prepare'.

Here is my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: *) do

create_table "deliveries", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "deliveryaddress"
t.integer  "deliverytime"
t.string   "notes"
t.integer  "orders_id"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

 add_index "deliveries", ["orders_id"], name: "index_deliveries_on_orders_id"

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "date"
t.string   "name"
t.string   "pickup"
t.datetime "pickuptime"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I assume this might be an error with the routes but I am uncertain.

How can I resolve this error?  Thank you.

Comment: add you migrations and relevant entries from your `schema.rb`. But the error means you are missing the column `order_id` on your deliveries tables. So either remove the relation between the classes or make sure the column is there

Comment: I've included my schema.rb above, which seems to indicate that I already have an **"orders_id"** column in my deliveries table.  Is that the problem (since it is plural instead of singular)?  If so, how do you recommend I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

going to make some assumptions here, but if you are following the Rails standard, then your column is named wrong:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deliveries
end

class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

So this requires the colum `order_id` to exist, not `orders_id`.
To fix this problem you need following migration:

```
class RenameOrderIdsCOlumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
     rename_column(:deliveries, :order_ids, :order_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, NekoNova!  Sorry, not sure how to implement this migration and I don't want to cause any additional errors.  To implement this fix, do I just input: 'rails generate migration RenameOrderIdsColumn order_id:string' in the command line?

Comment: use the command `rails g migration RenameOrderIdsColumn` and then update the generated file with the code I gave you. Then run the migration using `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change column name?

Use this command in rails 4 to generate a migration to rename a column.

```
rails g migration ChangeOrderIdToOrdersId
```